# Not Able to retrieve value from specific row <logic:iterate>

Tags: javascript, struts-1

I am iterating over a list and displaying value using bean:write, i am using a onfocus event to capture my row details and using

code something like this :

```
<logic:iterate id="empList" name="search" property="empList" indexId="index">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span id="empid"><bean:write name="empList" property="empID"/></span>
            </td>

            <td>
                <bean:write name="empList" property="firstName"/>
            </td>

            <td>
                <bean:write name="empList" property="lastName"/>
            </td>

            <td> 
                <html:button property="View" value="View" onfocus="viewPage()"/>          
            </td>
        </tr>
</logic:iterate>


<script>
function viewPage(){
var empid = document.getElementByID("empid).innerHTML;
}
</script>
```

but i am not able to get empid value in my javascript variable
Please help

Comment: Do share parsed/browser rendered HTML.. [___There must not be multiple `elements` in a `document` that have the same `id` value.___](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you used a wrong function name , it  is `getElementId()` the **d** should be in smaller case and also you didn't closed the double quotes.

Use this

`var empid =document.getElementById("empid").innerHTML;`

https://jsfiddle.net/cLL70bmq/

Answer (score 0):

set indexed="true" each field and take form elements to fetch values to the JS

```
<html:form action="something">
    <logic:iterate id="empList" name="search" property="empList" indexId="index">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span id="empid"><html:text name="empList" property="empID" styleId="empId" indexed="true"/></span>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <bean:write name="empList" property="firstName" indexed="true"/>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <bean:write name="empList" property="lastName" indexed="true"/>
                    </td>

                    <td> 
                        <html:button property="View" value="View" indexed="true" onfocus="viewPage(<bean:write name='index'/>)"/>          
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </logic:iterate>
</html:form>
```

and update your JS with

```
<script>
function viewPage(x){
var empid = document.forms[0].empId[x].value;
}
</script>
```

hope this helps you